# ACS Error Page Compilation Error

Tags: aem

After upgrading from AEM6.0 to AEM6.1 the ACS Not Found pages are no longer working. If I visit the error page specifically (/content/PROJECT/en/errors/404.html), then it renders and everything is fine. I'm not sure what steps I should take to troubleshoot this problem.

```
28.10.2015 15:43:42.247 *ERROR* [10.43.32.4 [1446061422243] GET /notapage HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.DefaultErrorHandler  Error    handler failed:java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException: Error handler failed: java.lang.Error
  at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:771)
  at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:442)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.DefaultErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:96)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl$1.render(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:345)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:77)
  at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
  at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:68)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.handleError(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:352)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:167)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:217)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:336)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:297)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:129)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
  The type com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
  The type com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Style cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
  The type com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
  The type com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.Component cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.NameConstants resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageManager resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Designer resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Design resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Style resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.EditContext resolves to a package
  Only a type can be imported. com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode resolves to a package
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.EditContext cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageManager cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.Component cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Designer cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Design cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Design cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Style cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.ComponentContext cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.EditContext cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageManager cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.components.Component cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Designer cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Design cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Design cannot be resolved to a type
  com.day.cq.wcm.api.designer.Style cannot be resolved to a type
  WCMMode cannot be resolved
  WCMMode.DISABLED cannot be resolved to a type

  at org.apache.jsp.apps.sling.servlet.errorhandler._404_jsp.<init>(_404_jsp.java:1)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.loadServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:165)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.prepareServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:434)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:102)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:536)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
  at org.apache.sling.servlets.resolver.internal.SlingServletResolver.handleError(SlingServletResolver.java:762)
  ... 67 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the problem was. I deleted /apps/acs-commons. I uninstalled and deleted the acs packages (all prior versions as well). Deleted /var/classes/subdirect. Then uploaded and installed acs. After that it worked.